# How to run a web browser as a screensaver

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, firefox, browser, screensaver

I would like to set up a custom application (a separate profile of Firefox browser in my case) to be fired instead of screensaver. I am using Gnome desktop environment. Technically it doesn't have to be a screensaver (xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver). What I want is for the application to be run whenever no keyboard/mouse input has been received for N minutes and to disappear (or minimize) after pressing a key.

Is it possible?

EDIT: Originally I've asked about Firefox only, but I would be fully satisfied with any other reasonable browser (like Chrome?).

Answer (score 12):

**If you're lazy and just want it to work, run this at terminal and choose the links you want to view**

```
cd ~/ && https://www.dropbox.com/s/yr17e7p7prae4o1/firefoxscript.sh && chmod +x ~/firefoxscript.sh && ~/firefoxscript.sh && rm ~/firefoxscript.sh
```

**Step by step instructions:**

This is what you want ([reference](http://mcmlxxii.co.uk/2009/04/19/turning-firefox-into-a-web-screensaver-using-a-bash-script/)):

**1) THIS MUST BE
 DONE WITH THE BROWSER CLOSED as
 Firefox overwrites the file on
 shutdown**
 - Open your firefox prefs file: `gedit .mozilla/firefox/*default/prefs.js`
 *(`*default` = your profile diretory)*

- Add these two lines at the end of the file:

  user_pref("browser.link.open_external", 1);
  user_pref("browser.link.open_newwindow", 1);

**2) Create a file (**`gedit ~/.webscreen`**) and paste this into it:**
*(change* `/home/huff/Desktop/pages` *to the right path of your user)*

```
#!/bin/bash

remoteclient=$(find /usr/lib/ -type f -name mozilla-xremote-client | grep -m 1 xulrunner)

if [ `ps -e | grep firefox | wc -l` -eq 0 ]; then

    /usr/bin/firefox -fullscreen &
    sleep 5

fi

while [ `ps -e | grep firefox | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; do

    urls=$(cat /home/huff/Desktop/pages)

    for i in $urls
        do
        $remoteclient -a firefox "openurl($i)"

        if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
            echo "Firefox not running or ignoring me, bailing out...."
            killall firefox
            exit 0
        fi
        sleep 15
        done
done
exit 0
```

**3) Make the file** ~/.webscreen **executable  ([Here's how to do that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35478/how-do-i-mark-a-file-as-executable-via-a-gui/35528#35528)).**

**4) Create a file named "pages" at your Desktop** `gedit ~/Desktop/pages` **with the links you want:**

Example:

> http://bbc.co.uk
>
> http://flickr.com
>
> http://yoursite.whatever.com

**5) Add a Custom Application Launcher to the panel.**

Enjoy! And thanks to [mcmlxxii](http://mcmlxxii.co.uk/author/admin/) ;-)

Comment: Reformatted your answer.

Comment: Edited to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @desgua could you upload this firefoxscript file again? The link seems to be dead.. Many thanks!

Comment: @sal of course! I have updated the link through my mobile phone. Right now I don't have any computer to test it. Can you please confirm that everything is OK?

Comment: The link works for me . . . (FWIW!) Impressive this was first posted in 2011. :)