# use web page or html file as a screensaver?

Tags: browser, html, xscreensaver

I heard that `xscreensaver` can run anything as a screensaver but I don't know how to do so. Can I use it to make a web page from an html file my screensaver?

Comment: to execute my app I use
`webbrowser-app --chromeless --fullscreen http://localhost/`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a web browser as a screensaver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31576/how-to-run-a-web-browser-as-a-screensaver)

Comment: It seems like "how to use firefox instead of xscreensaver" but i want to run `webbrowser-app` via `xscreensaver`. Everething is going to be good but xscreensaver adds sth like `-window-id 0x17001E87` to command and `webbrowser-app` returns "invalid URL"